# Probability of Ties

Tags: probability

I'm trying to verify my solution to a practice problem.  Here's the problem statement:

"Suppose 6 observations are taken at random from the uniform distribution on the interval [0, 1) and then rounded down to the nearest 10th of a unit.  Thus there are only 10 possible rounded values, and they are equally likely.  What is the probability there will be at least one tie among the rounded values?"

Here's how I approached it:

Let $X$ be the number of ties in 1 observation.  Then $P(X\geq 1) = 1 - P(X=0)$ = $P(\text{no ties in 1 observation})$.  To find $P(X = 0)$, we compute $P\left(\frac{\text{favorable outcomes}}{\text{total outcomes}}\right)$.

The number of favorable outcomes is the number of non-matching combinations, or ${10 \choose 2}$.  The number of total outcomes is the number of favorable outcomes + 10 matching pairs.  So $P(X = 0) = \frac{45}{55} = .8181$.  Since the observations are independent, $P(\text{no ties})$ = $P(X = 0)$ for 6 trials = $.8181^{6}$, or $.7$.  So $P(\text{at least one tie in 6 trials}) = 1 - .7 = 3$.

This feels right to me, but based on the solution to a similar problem, I have good reason to believe it's wrong.  Any comments would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is a tie? Two of the six observations are rounded to the same tenth?

Comment: I interpreted a tie as 2 of the 10 values are rounded to the same tenth.  But that might not be what the problem was asking, now that I'm looking more closely at it.

Comment: I don't understand your calculation.  As you say, you effectively have a $10$ sided die and you are asking for the probability of getting six distinct values in $6$ rolls.  Thats $1\times \frac 9{10}\times \cdots \times \frac 5{10}\approx .1512$.

Comment: Based on these comments, I think I've completely misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Thanks lulu!  I had taken the problem in completely the wrong way.  It's a simple permutation problem.  Wups!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider calculating the complimentary probability that no two of the six observations are the same.

Comment: Ugh. To compute p(no ties),   I have 10 choices for each observation.  There are 6 observations, so I 10^{6} possible outcomes.  The number of favorable outcomes is the number of distinct choices, or 10*9*8*7*6*5.  I have p(no ties) = 10*9*8*7*6*5/10^{6} = .1512, as lulu says.  Is this correct?

Comment: Exactly! ${}{}$